# LVM воcстановление данных

Tags: lvm, linux

Имеется lvm, на диске с ним бэд сектора, и операционка не грузится, какими средствами можно примонтировать lvm или какими-нибудь средствами слить с диска данные?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

1. загрузиться с флэшки (желательно большой)
2. сдампить нужный раздел, используя dd с опциями игнорирования испорченных разделов, на флэшку (или на свободное место на диске)
3. подмонтировать полученный образ
4. извлечь требуемые данные

Команда просмотра разделов

```
fdisk -l
```

Команда дампа

```
dd /dev/LVMVOLUME/NAME /mnt/name.iso bs=64k conv=noerror,sync
```

Команда монтирования

```
mount /mnt/name.iso /opt -o loop
```

Команда исправления возможных ошибок

```
fsck.ext3 /mnt/name.iso
```

Надо иметь в виду, что все это может занять очень много времени (dd выполняется долго для больших разделов).

Comment: Уже занимаюсь восстановлением и пришлось изрядно попотеть, итак исходя из своей специфики я делал следущее:<br>Для начала устанавливаем lvm2 и далее смотрим на наличие lvm - команда lvscan. Затем коннектим lvm -     vgchange -ay . Далее видим появившиеся устройства, с которыми можно уже работать<br> утилита dd - 3000 лет ждать из-за огромного количества ошибок не вариант. <br> dd_rescue и ddrescue - две волшебные и немного разные утилиты позволяют скопировать(причем вторая лучше читает данные вблизи сбойных секторов). Я предпочел вторую так как она быстрее у меня заработала.

Comment: dd не подходит также своей отказонеустойчивостью при чтении бэдов. В довесок, можно провести ремап битых секторов программами victoria и mhdd(Я бросил эту затею так не имею на это время). Их функционал очень схож. Ни в коем случае не использовать такую лажу как HDD Regenerator.  Упорете диск и уже ничто не поможет. Есть экзотика в виде охлаждения контроллеров стаканом со льдом либо вообще засунуть хард в морозилку. Но это самый-самый последний вариант.

Comment: Кстати следующая утилита на повестке, после дампа будет ext3grep - позволяет выдирать файлы с ext3, по очень разным критериям.